# Formatting job returned from input with Jquery

Tags: jquery, django, date, datetime, datepicker

I am trying to format these dates that I am receiving. I am intilizing the inputs like so:

```
$('#newEventStartDate').plusDatePicker();
$('#newEventEndDate').plusDatePicker();
```

After the user submits the form, I would like to collect the dates and submit them to my api with ajax. Django requires the date to be in YYYY-MM-DD format yet the date picker uses MM/DD/YYYY format. How can I convert the following date:

```
var eventData = {
      startDate: $('#newEventStartDate').val(), //right now it gives MM/DD/YYYY
      endDate: $('#newEventEndDate').val(),
    }
```

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
var eventData = {
      startDate: $('#newEventStartDate').plusDatePicker({ dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }).val(),
      endDate: $('#newEventEndDate').plusDatePicker({ dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }).val(),
    }
```

The value getting submitted to the model looks correct. This is the actual error i'm getting:

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'02/07/2017' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Answer (score 1):

In Django you can define the date input format, so it´s able to convert it into a datetime.date. You can do so by specifying

```
input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d']
```

in your DateField, if you are using a Django Form. Here's the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#datefield

Also, if you're not using a Form, you can parse the date using

`datetime.strptime(your_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()`

Comment: I looked over the datefield docs and it says you should be able to use 10/25/2006 but that's what I have..Here is my error: django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'02/07/2017' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you :

```
var d = new Date();

var curr_date = d.getDate();

var curr_month = d.getMonth();

var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

var date=new date(curr_year  + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date );
```